# C# map one to many object Query to complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have List of Custom type and I want to map this custom type to another complex type to represent one to many relationship.

`ViewModel` class contains data like this:

```
id name address
1   a    add1
1   b    add2
1   c    add3
2   aa   aaAdd
2   cc   ccAdd
3   aaa  aaaAdd
```

My code:

```
public class A  //class to map 
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> Data { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

var data= context.Database.SqlQuery<ViewModel>(query).ToList();
// query to get data, I want to map this ViewModel to List<A> class.
```

I can do it by foreach but I want another solution.

Can I get the result of class A like this?

```
[
    {id='1',[{a,add1},{b,add2},{c,add3}]},
    {id='2',[{aa,aadd1},{cc,ccdd2}]},
    {id='3',[{aaa,aaadd}]}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`GroupBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then construct the list of `B` using [**`Select`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
var data = context.Database.SqlQuery<ViewModel>(query)
    .ToList() // Execute the query first
    .GroupBy(q => q.Id)
    .Select(g => new A
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Data = g.Select(b => new B { Name = b.Name, Address = b.Address }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```